# convert uiviewcontroller to uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created an options screen in a viewcontroler however on reflection i wish to hold all this in a uiview instead.

The view controller holds various settings using nsuserdefaults and various switches ect

how would i go about switching this to a uiview?

I have created a class of uiview and tried to copy the files accros however this dose not work.

M file

```
#import "menuviewcontroller.h"

@interface menuviewcontroller ()

@end

@implementation menuviewcontroller

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [self.truthonoff setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] boolValue] animated:YES];

    [self.truthonoff addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.dareonoff setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"dareonoff"] boolValue] animated:YES];

    [self.dareonoff addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitcheddare:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.twoplayerswitch setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"twoplayerswitch"] boolValue] animated:YES];

    [self.twoplayerswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitchedtwoplayer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.groupswitch setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"groupswitch"] boolValue] animated:YES];

    [self.groupswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitchedgroup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)stateSwitched:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: tswitch.isOn ? @"YES" : @"NO" forKey:@"truthonoff"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(void)stateSwitcheddare:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: tswitch.isOn ? @"YES" : @"NO" forKey:@"dareonoff"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(void)stateSwitchedtwoplayer:(id)sender {

    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    [_groupswitch setOn:!tswitch.isOn animated:YES];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: tswitch.isOn forKey:@"twoplayerswitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: _groupswitch.isOn forKey:@"groupswitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(void)stateSwitchedgroup:(id)sender {

    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    [_twoplayerswitch setOn:!tswitch.isOn animated:YES];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: tswitch.isOn forKey:@"groupswitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: _twoplayerswitch.isOn forKey:@"twoplayerswitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}



@end
```

H file

```
NSString *truth;

@interface menuviewcontroller : UIViewController
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *truthonoff;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *dareonoff;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *twoplayerswitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *groupswitch;
@end
```

Comment: please also show your "converted" code

Comment: I have none as all i did was copy the code to a uiview class and this failed to work

Comment: Why change? It seems like this is the sort of code which wants to be in a controller. The logic for the program wants to be in a controller in the MVC model. Only logic involved in generic view manipulation wants to be in the view. For instance, if you had a view which turned red if a certain control were turned on, that'd go in the view, but if you wanted to record the state of that control in a file, that ought to go in the view controller.

Comment: Why don't you leave it a ViewController and use the .view property instead?

Comment: i was using two view controllers previously now i wish to only use one and use a uiview to hold the data. Could i just import all the data from second view controller to main?

Comment: I think i need to rethink this ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated above in some of the comments, it looks like some of this logic belongs in a view controller, but if you're set on turning this into a UIView, remember that view controller callbacks like `-viewDidLoad` and `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` will never be called on your UIView.

Any logic you are performing in `-viewDidLoad` should either be moved into the `-initWithFrame:` or `-initWithCoder:` of your UIView, or into an entirely new method (`-load` or something similar).

Also, make sure your storyboard is wired up correctly to actually instantiate all your UISwitches before you try to add all their targets.

Comment: Iv decided to use the same view controller now i just need to try and work that out thanks tho